# Not able to find the elements under nobr tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Not able to find the element with input tag. Need to find the element in the input tag. eclipse could catch the element till nobr and not further.

```
input id="ServiceFromDate" class="inactvDtTmTxt" name="$PHCClaimSearch$pServiceFromDate" data-ctl="["DatePicker"]" data-formatting="yes" value="05/02/2017" data-value="5/2/2017" style="padding-right:17px;width:11.719em;" validationtype="date" data-change="[["refresh", ["thisSection","", "", "&=", "", ",",":event","","HCClaimSearch"]]]" data-display-value="05/02/2017" type="text"/>
```

```js
//table[contains(@role,'presentation')][contains(@id,'pyActionArea')]//table[1]//table[contains(@role,'presentation')][contains(@section_index,'1')]//tbody//tr[2]//td[1]//following::nobr[1]//following::span[@id='$PHCClaimSearch$pServiceFromDateSpan']/input

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ServiceFromDate']")).sendKeys("04242015")
```

```html
<table id="" role="presentation" section_index="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="dataLabelWrite" style="height:24px;width:143px;">
 <td class="dataValueWrite" style="height:24px;width:190px;">
 <nobr>
<ins id="pega-calendar" style="display: none;" data-calendar="{"img":"webwb/pzspacercal_12860256145.gif!!.gif","locale":[["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59"],0,"M/d/yyyy","M/d/yyyy h:mm a","Today",["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],["AM","PM"],"Apply","Close"]}"/>
<script> var positionDatePickerIcn = function(control){ /* BUG-47098 - Following block filters out IE8(both quirks and standards modes) and IE9 (standards mode) */ var addMarginFlag = true; if(document.documentMode && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/4") > -1){ //IE8: skip for both standards and quirks mode addMarginFlag = false; } else if(document.documentMode && document.documentMode >= 9 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/5") > -1){ //IE9: skip for standards mode addMarginFlag = false; } if (addMarginFlag) { var icnEle = control.lastChild; if(icnEle.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img'){ icnEle.style.marginTop = '0px'; } } }; </script>
 <span id="$PHCClaimSearch$pServiceFromDateSpan" role="group" aria-label="Service From Date : " data-calendar="{"d":[0,0],"l":0}" style="display:inline-block; width:inherit;" onmouseover="pega.c.DatePicker.dtTmHvr(event);">
<input id="ServiceFromDate" class="inactvDtTmTxt" name="$PHCClaimSearch$pServiceFromDate" data-ctl="["DatePicker"]" data-formatting="yes" value="05/02/2017" data-value="5/2/2017" style="padding-right:17px;width:11.719em;" validationtype="date" data-change="[["refresh", ["thisSection","", "", "&=", "", ",",":event","","HCClaimSearch"]]]" data-display-value="05/02/2017" type="text"/>
<img class="inactvIcon" src="webwb/pzspacer_11792674401.gif!!.gif" data-ctl="["DatePicker"]" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
</span>
</nobr>
</td>
 <td class="dataLabelWrite" style="height:24px;width:125px;">
 <td class="dataValueWrite" style="height:24px;width:190px;">
 <td class="dataLabelWrite" style="height:24px;width:101px;">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the HTML, at least as you've pasted here.
there are a number of places inside that  tag that have double-quoted text inside of double-quoted text.  e.g. the input element has the following attribute:

```
data-ctl="["DatePicker"]"
```

Other attributes I found with this problem: data-calendar, data-change 
Once I corrected all of the places that this is a problem with outer single quotes, I was able to find the input using your Xpath from the Chrome developer tools

```
data-ctl='["DatePicker"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you could catch the element till `<nobr>` tag and not further that is because the `<ins>` tag is having `style="display: none;"`, so will use **`JavascriptExecutor`** to change the attribute and then send the text as follows :

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('pega-calendar').style.display='block';");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ServiceFromDate']")).sendKeys("04242015");
```